# In Android how to set image in DialogBox?

Tags: java, android, dialog

I created a dialogBox in my Android application.i want to show with image in that dialog Box.But i Cannot create image.kindly help me.
Thanks in Advance
here my Coding;

```
public void createbtnteam_adelaide()
{
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setMessage("What kind of Banner do you Want to Create?");
```

//my new code

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView) alertDialog.findViewById(R.drawable.team_brisbane);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.team_brisbane);

    alertDialog.setButton("Text Only", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          // here you can add functions
       }
    });


    alertDialog.setButton2("Text+Image", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              // here you can add functions
           }
        });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

}
i have Small icon in team_gwsid(imageid).

Answer (score 4):

The Android Developer site has an excellent article on how to create dialogs in Android, including custom dialogs. I think you solve your problem by having a look at that, it's pretty easy to do.

Here's the link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

*By the way (not related to this question): I see you've asked six questions here on StackOverflow, and haven't accepted any of them. This is usually what you do when someone helps you to solve your problems.*

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code you've tried to use?

Comment: Where is the part where you set the content view of the dialog? Also, the following part should not link to the drawable, but instead the ID of the ImageView in your layout: `ImageView image = (ImageView) alertDialog.findViewById(R.drawable.team_brisbane);`

Answer (score 0):

There ia a [`alertDialog.setView(View view)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setView%28android.view.View%29) method that enables you to set a custom view.

This does not affect the buttons or the titlebar.

Answer (score 0):

In standard dialog the icon is shown only if you set title too. You have to use `setTitle` to see result of `setIcon`. Icon is shown in title of the dialog.

Comment: @niva If you want to create dialog containing only image, or dialog containing image with message, you should look at link that Michell Bak send you in his answer. If you want to create dialog with title, icon and message, only thing you have to do is set all of this properties.

Comment: Sir i want message and icon.Message is displayed corrctly but image cannot displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can use Set icon or SetTitle to Display the Images in DialogBox. Read this [Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlertDialogSamples.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void createbtnteam_adelaide()
   {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.team_adelaide);
    alertDialog.setTitle("What kind of Banner do you Want to Create?");
    alertDialog.setButton("Text Only", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          // here you can add functions

       }
    });
    alertDialog.setButton2("Text+Image", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()                           
                   {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

              // here you can add functions
           }
        });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```